Is this function riemann integrable in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$?
Let $f[0,1]\times[0,1]\to [0,1]$ given by
$$f(x,y):=\begin{cases} 
0& x\notin Q\\
0& x=0\ x\in Q,y\in R-Q\\
\dfrac{1}{q}& x\in Q, y=\dfrac{p}{q}, \gcd(p,q)=1
\end{cases}$$
Is $f$ Riemann integrable?
I can find a P partition,where L(f,P)=0 (Lower sum), but for U(f,P) I only have this idea
$P=P_1 \times P_2, P_1=\{0,1\}, P_2=\{0,\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n-1},...,\frac{1}{2},1\}$
Then for $$p/q \in [1/k-1,1/k]\rightarrow p/q \leq 1/k \rightarrow 1/q<1/k$$
Then $M_{[1/(n-1),1/n]}(f)=1/n$
$$U(f,p)=\frac{1}{n}^2+\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k}(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k-1})$$
But this last serie don't converge to 0.
All of this is to prove the criterion
$$U(f,p)-L(f,p)<\epsilon$$
Other idea is to prove that the function is continuous in $I\times R$ but I don't know how to do it.

This is answered here.

see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3913376/integrability-of-generalization-of-thomaes-function-on-0-1-times-0-1?noredirect=1&lq=1
